# Any better way to write a multiple branched Mono flatMap

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

A non-reactive style code is like the following:

```
    public Response handleRequest(LoginContext ctx) {
        String username = ctx.getParameterMap().get("username");
        String password = ctx.getParameterMap().get("password");
        String ipAddr = ctx.getIpAddr();
        if (isIpAddressBlocked(ipAddr)) {
            return new Response("Your ip is blocked");
        }
        List<User> list = userCrudRepository.findByMobile(username);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
            return new Response("User not found");
        }
        if (list.size() > 1) {
            return new Response("Data abnormal, please contact the site administrator");
        }
        User user = list.get(0);
        if (DigestUtils.md5Hex(password).equals(user.getPassword())) {
            doWhenLoginSuccessfully(user);
            return new Response("Login successfully");
        } else {
            return new Response("Username or password error");
        }
    }
```

To rewrite it to a reactive style, I changed it to something like the following:

```
    @Autowired
    private UserCrudRepository userCrudRepository;
    
    private Map<String, Boolean> blockedIpMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    private Mono<Boolean> isIpAddressBlocked(String ipAddr) {
        return Mono.just(blockedIpMap.containsKey(ipAddr));
    }
    
    private Mono<Void> doWhenLoginSuccessfully(LoginContext ctx, User user) {
        ctx.getSession().getAttributes().put("loginStatus", 1);
        ctx.getSession().getAttributes().put("userId", user.getId());
        // This method is not finished yet.
        return Mono.just(0).then();
    }
    
    public Mono<Response> handleRequest(LoginContext ctx) {
        String username = ctx.getParameterMap().get("username");
        String password = ctx.getParameterMap().get("password");
        String ipAddr = ctx.getIpAddr();
        return isIpAddressBlocked(ipAddr)
                .filter((x)->x==Boolean.FALSE)
                .flatMapMany((x)->userCrudRepository.findByMobile(username))
                .collectList()
                .flatMap((x)->{
                    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(x)) {
                        return Mono.just(new Response("User not found"));
                    } else if (x.size() > 1) {
                        return Mono.just(new Response("Data abnormal, please contact the site administrator"));
                    } else {
                        User user = x.get(0);
                        if (DigestUtils.md5Hex(password).equals(user.getPassword())) {
                            return doWhenLoginSuccessfully(ctx, user)
                                .thenReturn(new Response("Login successfully"));
                        } else {
                            return Mono.just(new Response("Username or password error"));
                        }
                    }
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new Response("Your ip is blocked")));
    }
```

However, the ifs in the flatMap is not satisfying at all.

I wonder if there would be a better way to do this.

Thanks for your advises.

Comment: can you please add doWhenLoginSuccessfully?

Comment: Also why you method userCrudRepository.findByMobile(loginid) can return many items?

Comment: Please add other missing method you did in flux. I see multiple problems in your logic so please provide i will try to picture how i would do it

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm still on the progress of rewritting so actually not all methods had been completed.

Comment: userCrudRepository.findByMobile(username) can produce more than 1 item if there are some errornous data in the db.

Comment: Start out by placing the `ctx` in a mono and then flatMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit opinion based question but that's idea how I would do it.

```
package com.vob.reactive.webflux.service;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomService {

    private List<String> blockedIpMap =  asList("127.0.0.1");
    private List<User> users =  asList(
            new User("invalid", DigestUtils.md5Hex("password")),
            new User("invalid", DigestUtils.md5Hex("password1")),
            new User("valid", DigestUtils.md5Hex("password"))
    );

    private Mono<Boolean> isIpAddressBlocked(String ipAddr) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(blockedIpMap.stream().filter(ip -> ip.equals(ipAddr)).findFirst())
                .flatMap(c -> Mono.just(true))
                .defaultIfEmpty(false);
    }

    private Mono<Boolean> doWhenLoginSuccessfully(User user) {
        // This method is not finished yet.
        return Mono.just(true);
    }

    public Mono<User> findByMobile(String username, String password) {
        return Flux.fromStream(users.stream().filter(u -> u.username.equals(username)))
                .collectList()
                .flatMap(x -> {
                    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(x)) {
                        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("User not found"));
                    } else if (x.size() > 1) {
                        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Data abnormal, please contact the site administrator"));
                    }
                    User user = x.get(0);
                    if (!DigestUtils.md5Hex(password).equals(user.getPassword())) {
                        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Username or password error"));
                    }
                    return Mono.just(user);
                });
    }

    public Mono<String> handleRequest(String username, String password,  String ipAddr) {
        return isIpAddressBlocked(ipAddr)
                .flatMap(isBlocked->{
                    if(isBlocked){
                        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Your ip is blocked"));
                    }
                    return Mono.just(false);
                })
                .flatMap((x) -> findByMobile(username, password))
                .flatMap(this::doWhenLoginSuccessfully)
                .flatMap(x-> Mono.just("Login successfully"));
    }
    

    @Data
    public class User {
        private final String username;
        private final String password;
    }

}
```

Then Test

```
package com.vob.reactive.webflux.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

class CustomServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void success() {
        var service = new CustomService();
        StepVerifier.create(service.handleRequest("valid", "password", "10.0.0.1"))
                .expectNext("Login successfully")
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidPassword() {
        var service = new CustomService();
        StepVerifier.create(service.handleRequest("valid", "password2", "10.0.0.1"))
                .expectErrorMessage("Username or password error")
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    public void abnormal() {
        var service = new CustomService();
        StepVerifier.create(service.handleRequest("invalid", "password", "10.0.0.1"))
                .expectErrorMessage("Data abnormal, please contact the site administrator")
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    public void blockedIpWithRightPassword() {
        var service = new CustomService();
        StepVerifier.create(service.handleRequest("valid", "password", "127.0.0.1"))
                .expectErrorMessage("Your ip is blocked")
                .verify();
    }
}
```

I like this approach since its separating success and error, then in controller you can call service and map it to 200 OK or bad request 400

```
public Mono<Object> handleExample(String username, String password,  String ipAddr){
    return handleRequest(username, password, ipAddr)
            .onErrorMap(err-> // Return Error response)
            .flatMap();
}
```

Yes in the end you still have this flatMap with ifs but unfortunately thats your logic. I dont know much about your logic but i would rather do select from database with user and password so in the end you can get just mono.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm still new to reactive programming so I'm not sure about what is the good way to write the logics.

Comment: Keep it simple.